Azure function c# Kusto login issue
I try to login to Kusto from an azure function.
_kustoConnectionStringBuilder = new KustoConnectionStringBuilder(_kustoUri) .WithAadApplicationKeyAuthentication(applicationClientId, applicationKey, tenantId); 
Here the error happens:
return await kustoClient.ExecuteControlCommandAsync(_databaseName, command);
I got the error:
The type initializer for 'Kusto.Data.Security.HttpClientAuthenticatorFactory' threw an exception.
Inner exception:
FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'System.Diagnostics.DiagnosticSource, Version=8.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51'. Das System kann die angegebene Datei nicht finden.
Azure function:
Taregt framework net6.0
Function version v4
Nuget:
Microsoft.Azure.Kusto.Data Version=12.2.3
When I run the same code with same login from a console, then it works.

Check if the below solution helps to fix the issue.


The type initializer for 'Kusto.Data.Security.HttpClientAuthenticatorFactory' threw an exception. Inner exception: FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'System.Diagnostics.DiagnosticSource, Version=8.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51'

To resolve this error, add  <FunctionsPreservedDependencies Include="System.Diagnostics.DiagnosticSource.dll"/> in .csproj:
 <ItemGroup>
   <None Update="host.json">
     <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
   </None>
   ...
  <FunctionsPreservedDependencies Include="System.Diagnostics.DiagnosticSource.dll"/>
 </ItemGroup>

I could login to Kusto using below code in Azure function:
public static async Task<IActionResult> Run(
    [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Anonymous, "get", "post", Route = null)] HttpRequest req,
    ILogger log)
{
    log.LogInformation("C# HTTP trigger function processed a request.");

    var kustoUri = "https://<kustoCluster>.<region>.kusto.windows.net";
    var tableName = "<TableName>";
    var appId = "<App_Client_ID>";
    var appKey = "<Client_Secret>";
    var authority = "<Tenant_ID>"; 
    
    var kustoConnectionStringBuilder = new KustoConnectionStringBuilder(kustoUri)
        .WithAadApplicationKeyAuthentication(appId, appKey, authority);
    using (var kustoClient = KustoClientFactory.CreateCslAdminProvider(kustoConnectionStringBuilder))
    {
        var command = CslCommandGenerator.GenerateTableCreateCommand(
            tableName,
            new[]
            {
    Tuple.Create("StartTime", "System.DateTime"),
    Tuple.Create("EndTime", "System.DateTime"),
            }
        );
        await kustoClient.ExecuteControlCommandAsync("kpdb", command);
        return new OkObjectResult("Created a table in Kusto");
    }

Response:


Table got created under Kusto Cluster => Database:



Version 12.2.4 of the package was just released with a fix for this issue
